# Is it possible to create only one view swipeable in viewpager android

Tags: android, view, textview, android-viewpager, swipe

I am using viewpager in my application and i want to make only one view Swipeable . Is it possible to do so.
[image: Here is what i currently have]
I don't want the buttons at the bottom move when i swipe i only want the textview to change.
[image: Here is what I want]

Any way can anyone help i searched a lot but couldn't find anything.

Here is my code.
There is a lot of code i can't paste all of it here.
[Here is the link to the rest of it.](https://gist.github.com/ElyteLabs/4c00d28aee3c1008a75f70d5f44d7527)

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private Cursor cursor;
private int i = 0;
private int f = 0;

OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity activity, Cursor cursor) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.cursor = cursor;

}
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cursor.getCount();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    final Context context = container.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quote_detail_viewpager, container, false);

    final TextView tvQuotes;
    final ImageButton favouriteBtn, shareBtn, copyBtn, bgBtn, fontBtn;

    tvQuotes = v.findViewById(R.id.vp_quotes);
    favouriteBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.vp_fav);
    shareBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.vp_share);
    copyBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.vp_copy);
    bgBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.vp_bg);
    fontBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.vp_font);

    int[] fonts = {
            R.font.architects_daughter, R.font.artifika, R.font.carter_one,
            R.font.expletus_sans, R.font.fredoka_one, R.font.graduate, R.font.jose,
            R.font.magnolia, R.font.oswald, R.font.quicksand_bold, R.font.righteous,
            R.font.salsa, R.font.schoolbell, R.font.sofadi_one
    };
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    String id = cursor.getString(0);
    String quote = cursor.getString(1);
    String author = cursor.getString(2);
    String text = quote + "\n \n -  "+ author;

    if (new DatabaseHelper(context).isFavourite(id)) {
        favouriteBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
    }


    tvQuotes.setText(text);
    tvQuotes.setTypeface(PrefUtils.getTypefaceFromPrefs(context));

    favouriteBtn.setOnClickListener(view ->
            UtilsHelper.addOrDeleteFavourite(context, favouriteBtn, id, quote, author));

    shareBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> UtilsHelper.shareTextIntent(context, text));

    copyBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> UtilsHelper.copyText(context, text));

    bgBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view));

    fontBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        int j = f++;
        if (j < fonts.length) {

            PrefUtils.setTypefaceFromPrefs(context, fonts[j]);
            tvQuotes.setTypeface(PrefUtils.getTypefaceFromPrefs(context));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (f == fonts.length) {
            f = 0;
        }
    });

    container.addView(v);
    return v;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view);
}
}
```

DetailActivity.java

```
public class QuoteDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Max swipe ad interval
private final int MAX_AD_COUNT = 10;
// count swipes
private int SWIPE_COUNT = 0;
// Min swipe ad interval
private int MIN_AD_COUNT = 6;
private int i = 0;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

RelativeLayout rootLayout;
int[] backgrounds;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide(); //hide the title bar
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote_detail);

    showInterstitialAd();

    // String extras
    String incomingActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.STRING_EXTRA_INCOMING_ACTIVITY);
    int position = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constants.STRING_EXTRA_ADAPTER_POSITION, 0);

    DatabaseHelper mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.single_quote_viewpager);

    backgrounds = BackgroundUtils.getAllBackgrounds();
    rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.root_container);
    rootLayout.setBackgroundResource(BackgroundUtils.getBackground(position));

    FrameLayout adContainerView = findViewById(R.id.ad_view_container);
    adContainerView.post(() ->
            AdHelper.loadBanner(this, adContainerView, viewPager));


    assert incomingActivity != null;
    if (incomingActivity.contains(Constants.ACTIVITY_QUOTES)) {
        pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, mDBHelper.getAllQuotes());

    } else if (incomingActivity.contains(Constants.ACTIVITY_FAVOURITE)) {
        pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, mDBHelper.getFavourites());
    }

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position); // Setup recycleView Item position

    pagerAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ViewPagerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view) {
            changeBackground();

        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            int count = SWIPE_COUNT++;
            if (count >= MIN_AD_COUNT) {
                if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show(QuoteDetailActivity.this);
                    SWIPE_COUNT = 0;
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

private void changeBackground() {

    int j = i++;
    if (j < backgrounds.length) {
        rootLayout.setBackgroundResource(backgrounds[j]);
    }
    if (i == backgrounds.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
}

private void showInterstitialAd() {

    MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
    });
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    InterstitialAd.load(this, getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit),
            adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                    // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                    // an ad is loaded.
                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;

                    mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
                            if (MIN_AD_COUNT < MAX_AD_COUNT) {
               
                                MIN_AD_COUNT++;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                            // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                            // show it a second time.
                            mInterstitialAd = null;
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    // Handle the error
                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, something like the below pseudo_xml

```
<Parent View> -- background set to image

    <ViewPager> --  only this part is swipable

    <View Containing Buttons Fixed To The Bottom Of Parent/>

</Parent View>
```

Comment: but the problem is i want to change the font of my textview with one of the buttons, can i do that from the parent activity

Comment: You can yes. That would warrant a new question